# where is the problem thats create an Infinite loop on my code?

Tags: javascript

im creating a function that ment to find a string that is the same as 'HOH', fom an a array  initial array :  ['H','B' ,'C', 'N' ,'O', 'F'] ;
also, i need to find how many times it took to create a string like that.

my logic was somthing like this:

1. take the array and replace it to its numeric reprsention.
2. random the index, so on every run , each index will ricieve a different value.
   3.replace the random array back to string.
3. than slice a 3 char from the array, turn them into a string, and compare,
4. create a couner var , that whebever i ricieve the worng string will be +1;
5. since on every run i get a different random string, i tought to run a while.
6. i ricieve an Infinite loop and i cant find where is my problem.

```
console.log(atoms()); 
function atoms() {
    var counter=0;
    var atoms = ['H','B' ,'C', 'N' ,'O', 'F'];
    var atomsStr = atoms.join('');
    var getAtoms=[];
    var idx=0;
    var  strSlice=[]; // =''
    for (var i = 0; i < atomsStr.length; i++) {
        getAtoms.push(atomsStr.charCodeAt(i)) ;
    }  
    while (strSlice !=='HOH') {
    for (var j = 0; j < getAtoms.length; j++) {
        idx = getRandomIntInclusive(0,getAtoms.length-1);
        getAtoms[idx] = getAtoms[j];
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < getAtoms.length; k++) {
        getAtoms.splice(k,1,String.fromCharCode(getAtoms[k]))
    }
    counter++;
    strSlice = getAtoms.slice(3).join('');
    }
console.log(counter);
return  strSlice ; 
}


function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.ceil(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
```

really appreciate the help.
thank you .
any other advice on a more efficient approch or aother mistakes i did , are weloome.

Comment: At the second round `getAtoms` holds characters, not charcodes. So `String.fromCharCode(getAtoms[k])` will be equivalent to `String.fromCharCode(NaN)`, which results in `\u0000` and at third round, your `getAtom` array only contains this `\u0000` character, forever.

Comment: you can debug this fairly easy by adding sth like `.. if( counter> 15){ return false ..` inside for-loop and use console.log to check all values, this way it will not run infinite

Comment: thank you . but im still missing somthing. if i console.log getAtmos on the second loop i get :  [72, 78, 67, 67, 78, 67], and on the this i get string like this : ["H", "N", "C", "C", "N", "C"] . so it seems that  this for loop is working. at lesat on its first run. hopefully you can explain a little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have to improve your method.**
You're manipulating to much variables for a simple problem, first, don't use charCode like this, just create a function to get a random element from your array, that's way *easily*, *efficient* and *comprehensible*.

Next time, add more comment in your code to explain what you're trying to do ;)

Check out this simple script that work as you need:

```js
function atoms() {
  let attemptsNumber = 0,
    found = false;
  const baseAtoms = ['H', 'B', 'C', 'N', 'O', 'F'];
  while (!found) {
    attemptsNumber++;
    shuffledArray =
      getRandomItemFromArray(baseAtoms) +
      getRandomItemFromArray(baseAtoms) +
      getRandomItemFromArray(baseAtoms);
    // console.log(shuffledArray);
    found = shuffledArray === 'HOH';
  }
  return attemptsNumber;
}

// Fonction to get a random item from an passed arrays
// https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/get-random-item
function getRandomItemFromArray(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

// OUTPUT RESPONSE
console.log(atoms());
```